# Using sigmoid output for cross entropy loss on Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

I’m trying to modify Yolo v1 to work with my task which each object has only 1 class. (e.g: an obj cannot be both cat and dog)

Due to the architecture (other outputs like localization prediction must be used regression) so sigmoid was applied to the last output of the model (f.sigmoid(nearly_last_output)). And for classification, yolo 1 also use MSE as loss. But as far as I know that MSE sometimes not going well compared to cross entropy for one-hot like what I want.

And specific: GT like this: `0 0 0 0 1` (let say we have only 5 classes in total, each only has 1 class so only one number 1 in them, of course this is class 5th in this example)

and output model at classification part: `0.1 0.1 0.9 0.2 0.1`

I found some suggestion use `nn.BCE` / `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` but I think I should ask here for more correct since I’m not good at math and maybe I’m wrong somewhere so just ask to learn more and for sure what should I use correctly?

Answer (score 5):

1. `MSE` loss is usually used for regression problem.
2. For binary classification, you can either use `BCE` or `BCEWithLogitsLoss`. `BCEWithLogitsLoss` combines sigmoid with BCE loss, thus if there is sigmoid applied on the last layer, you can directly use `BCE`.
3. The GT mentioned in your case refers to 'multi-class' classification problem, and the output shown doesn't really correspond to `multi-class` classification. So, in this case, you can apply a `CrossEntropyLoss`, which combines softmax and log loss and suitable for 'multi-class' classification problem.